# What does a match on an empty enum return?

Tags: enums, rust

When reading [Rust's convert.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/315fbf7518dbcace5b92eabab746ba0a2c5531fa/src/libcore/convert.rs#L59-L69), I encountered the following code:

```
#[unstable(feature = "try_from", issue = "33417")]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, Hash, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub enum Infallible {}

#[unstable(feature = "try_from", issue = "33417")]
impl fmt::Display for Infallible {
    fn fmt(&self, _: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
        }
    }
}
```

`Infallible` is an empty enum with no variants. What does `match *self {}` return?

Answer (score 11):

Since `Infallible` has no possible values, you can never have an instance of it. This means matching on it can never happen. Rust represents this by making matching on an empty enum yield the `!` type, which is a builtin type that has no values.

This type coerces to any other type, because the statement can never be reached, because you'd need a value of type `Infallible` for that, which you can't have out of obvious reasons.

Comment: If it's unreachable, why `match *self {}` is used here instead of `unreachable!()`?

Comment: @Cheng-ChangWu and why would it implement `Display` anyway?

Comment: @Cheng-ChangWu that's probably because `match *self {}` produces no code, while `unreachable!()` produces panic code that will need to get optimized out